# Copying values from one field to another in a Django model

Tags: django, django-models

I have a Django model which has fields like: prodId, price, current stock, previous stock etc. The current stock data changes in an hour or so. Now whenever that happens, I need to copy values from current stock column into previous stock column and update the current stock column(along with prodId, price etc.) by fetching data from a server. Also, in the fetched data, I am just getting prodId, price and current stock, not the previous stock. In all, I need to fetch data from server, copy data from one field to another and then populate the model again from the fetched values. How can the desired functionality be achieved using Django?

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you are getting the data from the server as a json which when parsed gives a dictionary.

```
json_data = data_from_server()
dict_data = json.loads(json_data)
prod_id = dict_data['product_id']
product = Product.objects.get(product_id=prod_id)
product.previous_stock = product.current_stock
product.current_stock = dict_data['current_stock']  #update current stock got from server
product.price = dict_data['price']
product.save()
```